# Performing computation following groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe with four columns(I have simplified it, and it is also much longer). The user weights are always one, so their responses are treated equally. Although the same three users are assigned to each post in this example, users are actually randomly assigned to posts and each post has a variable amount of users assigned to it.

```
Post      userid     Weight  Response
-----     --------    ------  ---------
text1      A           1        0
text2      A           1        1
text1      B           1        0
text2      C           1        1
text1      C           1        1
text2      B           1        0
```

I want the resulting dataframe to look like the following, after grouping by post. Average response just averages the users' responses by post (so if 0 represents false and 1 true, then this would essentially gauge how true or false users claim the post is). The second column indicates the agreement (so 1 is perfect agreement, and the higher the score, the better).

```
Post      Avg_Response     Agreement
-----     ------------     ---------
text1       0.33            0.66
text2       0.66            0.66
```

I am confident for how to compute the average response (using the mean function), but I am not sure how to compute the agreement (the last column using pandas. I am sure there are some simple tricks to do this in one of two lines. My guess would be to count the number of 0s and 1s for each post divided the total number of responses for that divided. We would then take the ratio that is greater. If they are equal, then we get rid of them (so we don't want any posts in which users are evenly divided).

I would greatly appreciate help with code! Thank you.

Comment: `df.groupby(['post'].agg('mean')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO("""
Post      userid     Weight  Response
text1      A           1        0
text2      A           1        1
text1      B           1        0
text2      C           1        1
text1      C           1        1
text2      B           1        0
"""), header=1)

mn = df.groupby(['Post'])['Response'].mean()
md = df.groupby(['Post'])['Response'].agg(lambda x: max(np.mean(x), 1 - np.mean(x)))

mn.name = 'Avg_Response'
md.name = 'Agreement'
df2 = pd.concat([mn, md], axis=1)
df2
```

Yielding...

```
       Avg_Response  Agreement
Post
text1      0.333333   0.666667
text2      0.666667   0.666667
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up coming to something similar on my own (my bad for not seeing it earlier), but thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without needing `pd.concat`. Name the custom functions using `__name__`, and pass them as list.

```
def simple_mean(x):
    return x.mean()

def custom_mean(x):
    return max(x.mean(), 1-x.mean())

simple_mean.__name__ = 'Avg_Response'
custom_mean.__name__ = 'Agreement'

df.groupby('Post')['Response'].agg([simple_mean, custom_mean])

       Avg_Response  Agreement
Post
text1      0.333333   0.666667
text2      0.666667   0.666667
```